# Difference in HTML Encoders in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, encoding

What is the difference between these 3 different HTML encoding technique available in ASP.NET Core

Class ( we can use Dependencycy Injection)
`System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder`

Static Method
`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()`
`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`

Are they all same and outputs the same encoded string?

Comment: For the difference between `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()` and `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`,you can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=net-6.0),it said `To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the WebUtility class.`